# bash: xargs passing variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, xargs

How can a global script variable be passed to the command of xargs? I tried it this way:

```
TEST=hallo2
echo "hallo" | xargs sh -c 'echo passed=$1 test=$TEST' sh
```

Output:

```
passed=hallo test=
```

I know I could use the `{}` token but I need to do it this way!

I'm using `bash`.

Comment: try using `export TEST=hallo2`

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós: add that as an answer. It's the safest, most correct approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take variable `$TEST` out from the quotes:

```
 TEST=hallo2
 echo "hallo" | xargs sh -c 'echo passed=$1 test='$TEST sh
```

Comment: If you take this approach, you should double-quote `$TEST` to guard against it containing whitespace.

Answer (score 12):

Added as an answer as@chepner suggested.

`export` the variable `TEST`:

```
export TEST=hallo2
echo "hallo" | xargs sh -c 'echo passed=$1 test="$TEST"' sh
```

Comment: This should be considered as the correct answer as the variable is actually passed within sh -c '.....'. Thanks solved my problem.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the variable `TEST` inside `xargs`?

Answer (score -5):

With GNU Parallel you can avoid some of the quoting:

```
TEST=hallo2
echo "hallo" | parallel echo passed={} test=$TEST
```

GNU Parallel exists as package for most distributions and it is recommended to use the normal package manager for installation. But if there is no package for your system, it still takes literally 10 seconds to install GNU Parallel.

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: I strongly recommend not to pipe some script from a random site in a stack overflow answer, to your shell.